# JavaScript multiple inputs onChange

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

I've got a problem. There's a shopping cart (shown as table) in the application based on Zend framework. Every row is a product in the shop basket. Every row has **two** form fields: quantity and value (= price*quantity).

I want to change the value by quantity (price*quantity) with the `onChange` event with JavaScript, but I don't know how to do this with number of rows > 1. Inputs are given in the `foreach` loop in the Zend view.

Is there any universal algorithm in JavaScript to solve this?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Does each value field have e.g. an ID attribute that can be derived from the ID of the quantity field? If so, then it's pretty quick and painless. Given:

```
<table id="basket">
    <tr class="basket-row">
        <td class="basket-quantity">
            <input type="text" id="product1234_quantity">
        </td>
        <td class="basket-subtotal">
            <input type="hidden" id="product1234_unitprice" value="20">
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="product1234_subtotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="basket-row">
        <td class="basket-quantity">
            <input type="text" id="product5678_quantity">
        </td>
        <td class="basket-subtotal">
            <input type="hidden" id="product5678_unitprice" value="30">
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="product5678_subtotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here, the unit price for each product is in a hidden attribute, but I don't know where your cart stores it. Let's assume you can get it from somewhere, and let's assume jQuery.

```
$('#basket').on('change','.basket-quantity input',function(e) {
    $('#'+this.id.replace('_quantity','_subtotal')).val(Number($('#'this.id.replace('_quantity','_unitprice')))*Number(this.value));
});
```

If you can't derive IDs from other IDs, you'd have to do some more complex DOM querying, but the point is, at runtime of the handler, you have to figure out what input you're updating.

You didn't specify what (if any) framework you are using. In plain JS this would require a lot of extra code to make it cross-browser compatible, to normalize event attachment and handling.

Comment: great.. looks fine, i'll try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

in for each you can use

```
$(this).index()
```

e.g

```
$("#jieguo_qian table tr:nth-child(4) td").each(function(){
    var tindex = $(this).index() + 1;
```

so you can get the same td in the diff tr

```
th    th    th
td    td    td
td    td    td
```